# Oauth security in Spring

Tags: spring-security

How can i implement oauth security in our spring application.

Please provide me some tutorial/example code for that, i have googled many time but can't find any good tutorial or sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to http://oauth.net/documentation/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

We have written a Spring 4 / Java 8 application which does exactly that. It is open source and you can read about the security layer here http://blog.techdev.de/using-spring-oauth-in-trackr/